# Homology groups of compact surfaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have known that all compact surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are homotopic to one of $S^2, mT$ and $nP^2$, where $S^2$ the sphere, $mT= T\# T\#\cdots\# T$ the $m$-connected sum of torus, and $nP^2=P^2\#P^2\# \cdots\#P^2$ the $n$-connected sum of project surface $P^2$. I have also known how to compute the homology groups of $S^2, T, P^2$. The problem now is that how to deal with the connected sum? Any hint would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you know the Mayer-Vietoris exact sequence?

Comment: An alternative is to use the cellular homology, if you know what it is.